# Twilio Real-time speech to text in conference

Tags: twilio, real-time, voice-recognition, speech-to-text, conference

Is it possible to make real-time voice recognition during conference in Twilio? I do it for single call but I need do it for conference. Thank you for your help

Comment: Imagine how confusing your transcript would be. I guess you would have to record the individual calls instead of the conference. Theres a beta feature which allows you to receive a webhook when a participant speaks or stops speaking. If you were good you could couple that with the REST API to redirect callers who are start speaking to new TwiML which starts recording and stop when they do, but I dont know if you can actually start recording after you have set up a call

Comment: @miknik If you redirected speakers away when they started to talk, no-one in the conference call would ever hear anything! Sadly, this is just a feature that doesn't exist within Twilio.

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: Please also see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: This works in voximplant, but not in twilio

Comment: I think it is now, although I can't figure out how. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am74WU1zENA&feature=youtu.be&t=727)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no live speech recognition in [Twilio conferences](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference).

Comment: I'm wondering it could works if I buy two numbers on twilio and set on them voice real-time voice recognition and them connect audio of these two calls? The second question is it is possible to connect two calls? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can't connect two calls and have them doing voice recognition at the same time, no. Currently live voice recognition is done by connecting a single call leg with TwiML that says [`<Gather input="speech">`](http://twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). There's no way to connect two calls to both another caller and some alternative TwiML at the same time.

Comment: How do you explain [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am74WU1zENA&feature=youtu.be&t=727)

Comment: Oh, that was a demo that hasn’t been released yet.

Comment: is this still not possible? what about doing that with a taskRouter call?

Comment: @AlfredoDaAs Now available for all voice calls is [Twilio Media Streams](https://www.twilio.com/media-streams), which gives you a real time feed of the audio in a call. With this, you can put your conference call through a speech to text API to get speech recognition.